# Unix Shell script archive previous month file

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory containing files named like

```
SLS20160112.001    (20160112 stands for YYYYMMDD)
```

I wish to archive all previous month's files. For example, given:

```
SLS20150201.001
SLS20160107.001
SLS20160130.001
SLS20160201.001
```

I will archive `SLS20160107.001` and `SLS20160130.001` because these two files have a January 2016 name and it's currently February 2016.

For the `SLS20160201.001` (February 2016) should not be archived, as I only want to archive previous month's file. Note that I can only consider the filename, not the mtime or atime

My current logic is to loop through all files, then get previous month files and then pipe out the filename and tar it. But not sure how to do that part.

```
for file in SLS*; do
   f="${file%.*}"

GET PREVIOUS MONTH FILES AND THEN ECHO

done | tar cvzf SlSBackup_<PREVIOUS_MONTH>.TAR.GZ -T-
```

Answer (score 3):

With GNU `date`, you can use the `-d` switch and plain-English descriptions to get an arbitrary date.  For example, `date -d "one month ago"`.  So, we can work thusly:

```
FILESPEC="SLS$(date -d "1 month ago" +"%Y%m")??.001"
LASTMONTH="$(date -d "1 month ago" +"%m")"
IFS=

tar cvzf "SlsBackup_${LASTMONTH}.tar.gz" $FILESPEC
```

Happily, this is smart enough that if you run it in, say, Jan 2017, it will rightly back up the files for Dec 2016.

Comment: is there any command for 1 year ago? maybe like LASTYEAR="$(date -d "1 year ago" +"%m")"

Comment: There sure is.  It's pretty interesting to see just how robust the `-d` parsing is.  You can even do such craziness as `date -d 'tuesday last week` or `date -d '464 days ago`.  See the `DATE STRING` section of `date`'s manual page.